# How write count Aggregation function if it equals the string count should increase other wise no need to increase in BIRT REPORT?

Tags: java, eclipse, report, birt

I try to count number of rejected data in my column by using Aggregation COUNT function in footer part, In expression i wrote below expression but it is not working.

**Expression** => **dataSetRow["ReasonCode"]== "REJECT"**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a data set field whose values to perform the aggregate calculation.
   Expression-->row["fieldName"]
2. In Filter Condition, specify the filter condition to use to determine which rows are factored in the aggregate calculation
   Condition-->dataSetRow["condintionFieldName"]=="CondintionText"
   Aggregate On--> Table

Answer (score 0):

Say for example that your query returns 5 rows and that the "==" expression returns the 5 values [true, false, false, false, true]. Now your count is 5.

But brobably you WANT to count the 2 true values only.

I would change the "Expression" to true and use the javascript "==" construct expression inside the "Filter condition" instead.